# After update php 7.1 - 7.3.15 Class 'mysqli' not found

Tags: php, mysqli, opencart, freebsd

I'm using **Opencart 3.0.2** on FreeBSD. I need to install a zip module to be able to install the OpenCart extension, but **PHP 7.1** is out of date and no longer supports module installation. So I decided to upgrade the PHP to version **7.3.15**. After updating and installing all the required modules,

I got a fatal error:

> Class 'mysqli' not found

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/ext-05-ioncube.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-18-session.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-ctype.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-curl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-dom.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-filter.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-hash.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-json.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-mbstring.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-mysqli.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-openssl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-xml.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-zip.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-20-zlib.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/ext-30-memcache.ini

[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
gd
hash
ionCube Loader
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
Reflection
session
SPL
standard
xml
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
the ionCube PHP Loader
```

Comment: Did you just try and drop the *php.ini* file from 7.1 into your 7.3 install? I'm noticing *mcrypt* is in the list of PHP Modules there - and that doesn't exist under 7.3.

Comment: You might have different PHP version in console and different in browser. When checking for installed modules be sure to also check if you are running correct PHP version

Comment: It was decided to upgrade the Apache module to the current version of PHP

Answer (score 0):

you need to install mysqli refer below link
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

after installed mysqli then still have a problem, please post your operating system and anything else that might help diagnose it further.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by upgrade the Apache module to the current version of PHP 
(apache-mod_php-7.3)